# Failed to load 'sap/ui/table/TreeTable.js'

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5, treetable

I'm trying to create a tree structure view from a json model using SAPUI5.
I haven't found solutions on the internet so this is why I'm asking here. 
Basically, despite having used the right code over and over again, It fails to load the TreeTable.js file, I have tried using multiple codes but no luck. 
I am loading the TreeTable on a Dialog. This is the code:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition 
xmlns="sap.ui.table"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:m="sap.m"
xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
<m:Dialog horizontalScrolling="true" showHeader="true" state="None" stretch="false" title="{Soluzione}" type="Standard" verticalScrolling="true" contentWidth="90%">
    <m:content>
        <TreeTable
        id="Tree"
        rows="{path: 'applicationModel>/AlberoSoluzioni'}"
        selectionMode="MultiToggle"
        enableSelectAll="false"
        ariaLabelledBy="title">
            
        </TreeTable>
    </m:content>
    <customHeader/>
    <endButton/>
    <subHeader/>
</m:Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Wondering what I'm doing wrong.
Error in console at loading:

```
Uncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/table/TreeTable.js' from resources/sap/ui/table/TreeTable.js: 404 - Not Found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add its `dependencies` in the `manifest.json` please check if you did so.

```
"sap.ui5": {
        "dependencies": {
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.table": {}
            }
        }
```

Also, check `src` in the bootstrap script in index.html

Comment: Great tip, but I get this error: 
Failed to load component for container container. Reason: Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/table/library.js' from resources/sap/ui/table/library.js: script load error

Comment: @manudicri there might be a version issue

Comment: I found out that the project I'm working on loads the resources locally, so it should work if I change the src url. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

First, install the ui5 cli :

> npm install --global @ui5/cli

Then from within your project directory, add the dependency :

```
ui5 add sap.ui.table
```

Then build and serve

```
ui5 build -a --clean-dest



ui5 serve
```